# What kind of concrete finish was used in this Tulum treehouse?

Tags: concrete, flooring

I'm remodeling my house and would like to finish the walls and floors as done in [this Tulum treehouse](https://www.dezeen.com/2017/09/05/tulum-treehouse-co-lab-architecture-design-office-guest-house-hotel-jungle-escape/). Who can tell me what kind of concrete finishing technique was used here?

In the linked Dezeen article they talk about "polished white concrete" but that is not very specific. The walls and floors have these beautiful shadows and swipe patterns in them that create a lively but natural look. How did they achieve this?

[image: tulum treehouse].

Comment: I can't tell what was done in the pictured house but I have seen walls with "shadows and swipe patterns", it is done by a skilled plasterer using techniques sometimes called Dyed Plaster, Tinted Plaster, Venetian Plaster, there are lots of ways to mix and apply these things and there are one or two brand names I can't remember that provide the tools and materials to do it.   I have also seen similar things done in concrete, also by skilled people who mix in dyes, stones, reflective beads, and so on and combine that with brushing and polishing techniques.

Comment: It could also be raw concrete just carefully & skillfully troweled to achieve a non-uniform finish. (I'm not sure how well plaster would hold up as a floor surface - maybe it would.)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I found some Venetian plaster photo's that indeed look similar.

Answer (score 1):

Floors probably have some kind of overlay maybe a  on top of concrete.  You can tell by the control lines in the floor that it was poured.  The control lines also show a different color.

It might be something like the "seamless natural floor plaster" picture here:

https://www.stuccoitaliano.com/floor-plasters

Walls are probably the same overlay on concrete block.

Comment: Yes, I came across that one in my search but that "seamless natural floor plaster" looks a bit more modern (does not have the same shadows/swipes) than the image I shared. But perhaps that is also just a matter of how it is applied. I've sent them an email to ask. Thanks!

Comment: This "micro-topping" (microcement) picture looks most like it of what I have found so far: https://www.idealwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/2020_03_Founders-Office-Abu-Dhabi_MT_26.jpg

Comment: Yeah this "ideal work" one looks similar too.  https://www.modernsurfacecollections.com  Seems like you'd have to order the micro topping from Italy.